# Align output numbers in tkinter Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning to use tkinter developing an application that at the end of calculation make a final report putting numbers in columns.

```
from tkinter import *

a = 5
b = 0.223
c = 0.1
a1 = 0.55556
b1 = 1.57
c1 = 785869
a2 = 785698
b2 = 0.55875968547854
c2 = 8696

root=Tk()
output_text = Text(root, width=200, height=30)
output_text.grid(row=10,column=10)
output_text.insert("end-1c", str(a) + ' ' + str(b) + ' ' + str(c)+'\n')
output_text.insert("end-1c", str(a1) + ' ' + str(b1) + ' ' +str(c1)+'\n')
output_text.insert("end-1c", str(a2) + ' ' + str(b2) + ' ' +str(c2)+'\n')

root.mainloop()
```

I want to align numbers in every column because every row has different number of digits so the output is not well organized. How can I obtain this result? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is the way we used to do it with typewriters: create and use tabstops, which are explicitly designed to allow you to line data up in columns.

The following example sets tabstop every 200 pixels:

```
output_text.configure(tabs=["200"])
...
output_text.insert("end-1c", str(a) + '\t' + str(b) + '\t' + str(c)+'\n')
output_text.insert("end-1c", str(a1) + '\t' + str(b1) + '\t' +str(c1)+'\n')
output_text.insert("end-1c", str(a2) + '\t' + str(b2) + '\t' +str(c2)+'\n')
```

You can specify the alignment of the tabstops by supplying one of the following values after the tab width: `"left"`, `"right"`, `"center"`, or `"numeric"`. `"numeric"` means that the decimal point will be placed at the tab stop.

```
output_text.configure(tabs=["200", "numeric"])
```

For the canonical definition of the tabs option, see the tcl/tk documentation here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M-tabs

note: the python tkinter documentation gives a nice overview of how to translate tcl/tk documentation into python in the section titled [Tkinter life Preserver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-life-preserver)